Prometheus query to get previous deployment image tag
I am looking for a query to see when a container's image tag changes within a pod with Prometheus and that return it previous value.
I tried to use
kube_pod_container_info{} != kube_pod_container_info{} offset 5m

But it only shows some dots in the past and most values are Nans.

At best, this is an anti-pattern use of PromQL. I suspect, it's not possible. I assume the Pod's containers' (there could be more than one) image tag is captured as a label value. You can use label values to identify and aggregate time-series values but, PromQL can only return computations that apply to time-series values (not label values).

I wholeheartedly agree with @DazWilkin, and describing this as an anti-pattern is putting it polite. Using the monitoring to effectively fix a container tag forever is a Very Bad Idea™. It will in the worst case start a battle with your deployment mechanism: the latter tries to update an image, your monitoring reverts it...

You are absolutely right. But this is not really about monitoring. The main idea is to display reference information about the service in a table in Grafana, incl. deployment version to which the rollback will be made. I couldn't find a way to do this for promql, but I could for metricsQL VM.  topk(3,tlast_over_time(group by(image)(kube_pod_container_info{container=~"$Container",container!="All",namespace=~"$NameSpace"})   !=    group by(image) (kube_pod_container_info{container=~"$Container",container!="All",namespace=~"$NameSpace"}) offset 5m )[$history_interval] )*1000

I don't really get get what you want, and cannot comment on correctness of your query, but AFAIK, tlast_over_time is merely a syntax sugar, and you can make equivalent query in promQL using max_over_time(timestamp( ..inner.. ) [range:resolution])
